# How do I find the subjectdistinguishedname of a x509 certificate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am trying to use the `X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName` option and I am not sure where to find the value for the `findValue` property in my config.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509findtype.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the subject field in IE: `Options -> Certificates -> Certificate -> Details -> Subject`.

It is a composite value and can be also extracted from a PEM certificate (on linux).

Comment: i'm supposed to string all those components together? how?